# Xml parse android code

Tags: android, xml, parsing

I am making an application for Android and I need to display an XML file of [this page:](http://www.bovalpo.com/cgi-local/xml_bcv.pl?URL=7009) In the application show `Compra="481.3" Venta="485"` but i cant `"DOLAR SPOT INTERBANCARIO" and Var_por="-0,53" Var_pes="-2,60" hora="10:35"`. Help me with the code please.

XML image [image: XML]

This is ExampleHandler code

```
public class ExampleHandler extends DefaultHandler {

private boolean in_Root = false;
private boolean in_Registro = false;

private ParsedExampleDataSet myParsedExampleDataSet = new ParsedExampleDataSet();

public ParsedExampleDataSet getParsedData() {
    return this.myParsedExampleDataSet;
}


@Override
public void startDocument() throws SAXException {
    this.myParsedExampleDataSet = new ParsedExampleDataSet();
}

@Override
public void endDocument() throws SAXException {
}


@Override
public void startElement(String namespaceURI, String localName,
        String qName, Attributes atts) throws SAXException {
    if (localName.equals("Root")) {
        this.in_Root = true;
    }else if (localName.equals("Registro")) {
        this.in_Registro = true;
        // Extract an Attribute
        String attrValue = atts.getValue("Compra");
        Float compra = Float.parseFloat(attrValue);
        myParsedExampleDataSet.setExtractedCompra(compra);

        String attrValue2 = atts.getValue("Venta");
        Float venta = Float.parseFloat(attrValue2);
        myParsedExampleDataSet.setExtractedVenta(venta);

        **String attrValue3 = atts.getValue("Var_por");
        Float por = Float.parseFloat(attrValue3);
        myParsedExampleDataSet.setExtractedPor(por);**
        //its my wrong code for  Var_por    
    }
}

@Override
public void endElement(String namespaceURI, String localName, String qName)
        throws SAXException {
    if (localName.equals("Root")) {
        this.in_Root = false;
    }else if (localName.equals("Registro")) {

    }
}

/** Gets be called on the following structure: 
 * <tag>characters</tag> */
@Override
public void characters(char ch[], int start, int length) {
    if(this.in_Registro){
        //myParsedExampleDataSet.setExtractedStruct(new String(ch, start, length));
    }
}
```

}

Comment: See [this](http://www.ibm.com/developerworks/opensource/library/x-android/)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You might check out SimpleXML for something small like that.  It works well on Android.

[SimpleXML parser](http://simple.sourceforge.net/)

Comment: my code works, just do not know how to show the other parameters of the xml

Answer (score 0):

I implemented a solution to this problem recently using [Jsoup](http://jsoup.org/).
The solution outlined below will both fetch the data from the supplied URL and parse it into an array of Strings.

**Setup**

The .jar file can be found [here](http://jsoup.org/download).

Instructions on how to include it in an Android app are [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1334802/how-can-i-use-external-jars-in-an-android-project).

**Implementation**

Imports used:

```
import org.jsoup.Jsoup;
import org.jsoup.nodes.Document;
import org.jsoup.select.Elements;

import java.io.IOException;
import java.util.ArrayList;
```

Function code:

```
public static ArrayList<String> parseDocument() 
{
    ArrayList<String> values = new ArrayList<String>();

    Document doc;
    try {
        doc = Jsoup.connect("http://www.bovalpo.com/cgi-local/xml_bcv.pl?URL=7009").get(); // Timeout is in milliseconds
        Elements nodes = doc.select("Registro");

        values.add( nodes.attr("tipo") );
        values.add( nodes.attr("Compra") );
        values.add( nodes.attr("Venta") );
        values.add( nodes.attr("Var_por") );
        // etc

    } catch (IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
    return values;
}
```

All you need to do once the function is returned is read the values from the ArrayList.

Comment: i have a quesstion, public static ArrayList<String> parseDocument()  is other class?

Comment: It is not itself a class. However, if you want you can wrap it in a class (for example a Utilities class or similar).
You can probably remove the "public static" part of the function declaration if it confuses you.

Comment: I'm new to programming, how read the values ​​from the ArrayList?

Comment: values.get(0); See full documentation for more: http://docs.oracle.com/javase/1.4.2/docs/api/java/util/ArrayList.html