# How to use wordpress Api in android application

Tags: java, android, wordpress, xml-rpc

I want to convert a Wordpress BLog into a Android app
The problem is that for retrieving posts , I need the net.bican.wordpress package 
How can I import the Package
or use another API

Comment: You're asking how to convert a website into an application....  Do you know how to program in Java?  If not, we won't teach you and maybe there's a tutorial out there for you.  What is your setup for your app?  Is it just the standard Eclipse IDE?  Importing a package is fairly straight forward, so what part of the process is giving you problems?

Comment: If by convert you mean retrieving the blog posts from the wordpress blog into the android app, check this similar question:
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12024811/how-to-retrieve-posts-from-a-wordpress-blog-in-an-android-app