# Noclassdeffounderror Jericho htmlparser

Tags: java, android, jericho-html-parser

I am working on an Android project which uses the Jericho html parser. The app starts, but when I want to use parser when pressing a search button, I get the following error:

```
java.lang.RuntimeException: An error occured while executing doInBackground()

Caused by: java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: net.htmlparser.jericho.Source

testapp.search.GetParser.<init>(GetParser.java:29)
```

I imported the Jerco html parser JAR file, so that shouldn't be the problem.. I have no idea why this error occures!

Any ideas?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I fixed it myself already, added the library as described in here:
[How can I use external JARs in an Android project?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1334802/how-can-i-use-external-jars-in-an-android-project)

Instead of adding the library on the properties panel of my project.