# how to import own jar into android project (ADT 20)

Tags: java, android, eclipse

If I import a selfmade jar file into my Android project (add it to the libs folder) I get an "Could not find class" error sent by dalvikvm. (I'm using Eclipse)

Obviously it's not an import error, because downloaded jars (like jdome) worke fine.

So I guess it's an export error. The way how I export a jar is: right click on project -> export -> jar -> leave default settings -> finish

I'm sure it's no internal problem, because the jar contains only one class which has only one method for test reasons.

Does anyone know what I did wrong?????

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How can I use external JARs in an Android project?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1334802/how-can-i-use-external-jars-in-an-android-project)

Answer (score 1):

Just copy and  paste your .jar  file in libs folder of your project.

Answer (score 0):

Yry this, I hope this will work for you:

- Go To Your Project
- Right Click
- Properties
- Java Build Path
- Libraries
- Add External Jar
- Select Jar File
- OK

Comment: Still doesn't work, but I just saw that dalvikvm sends an "Could not find class" error first of all