# Gradle downloads transitive dependencies, but shows compile error

Tags: java, gradle, pom.xml, gradle-dependencies

I published a jar in my repo, lets call it A.jar, which generated following dependency in pom:

```
<dependency>
  <groupId>org.json</groupId>
  <artifactId>json</artifactId>
  <version>20180130</version>
  <scope>compile</scope>
</dependency>
```

In another project, lets call it B, I have declared following dependency in the build.gradle:

```
compile 'my.test:A.jar' // With version etc, just to illustrate.
```

In the files used by this project B, I get following compile error:

> error: cannot resolve symbol JSONArray

This JSONArray is part of the org.json.json library.

Am I forced from Project B build.gradle to add also the compile dependency for org.json? is this the default behaviour?

```
--> compile group: 'org.json', name: 'json', version: '20180130'
```

From my point of view, it should make sense that when I am already downloading required dependencies for A.jar, it also adds them as dependencies to Project B

Comment: I think you must download the jar on your path.
Check that: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13155200/org-json-simple-cannot-be-resolved

Comment: Please post your full `build.gradle` file or at least the parts responsible for dependencies, in detail the `repositories` and the `dependencies` block.

Comment: I faced a similar problem, and I suspect that the problem is that version number is not of the form of a classic x.y.z.

Comment: Yes it might be related to : https://github.com/gradle/gradle/issues/1487