# Can't access org.json.JSONObject in Kotlin project

Tags: java, kotlin

I just installed IntelliJ IDEA and Kotlin, and I'm trying to get a simple JSON parser to run using the Java org.json library. But for some reason, I'm unable to access the JSONObject in org.json. Any ideas why this is happening? I added the latest version through Maven.

JDK 1.8

IntelliJ 2019.1.2 CE

[image]

Forgive me if this is a silly question.

Comment: You can find the answer here. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13155200/org-json-simple-cannot-be-resolved

Answer (score 0):

The answer is actually pretty simple --beginner's mistake. IntelliJ IDEA's Maven search isn't the best, so I accidentally used the wrong JSON library. I had to scroll through a ton of libraries and I eventually found the right org.json library.

Problem fixed.