# Only one Row record show on the datatable using Jsp Ajax

Tags: ajax, jsp

i need to view records in to the Datatable using jsp json. data is displayed  to datatable successfully. my problem is only one row data is displaying.the last row of database record is repecting 4 times.i attached image below what was shown on the datatable and what are the data inside mysql database.

Record Shown one the datatable look like this.data duplicated

[image]

Mysqldata Data

[image]

**Datatable**

```
    function get_all()
{
    $('#tbl-projects').dataTable().fnDestroy();
    $.ajax({
        url : "all_project.jsp",
        type : "GET",
        dataType : "JSON",

        success:function (data){
                console.log(data);
            $('#tbl-projects').dataTable({
                "aaData": data,
                "scrollX": true,
                "aoColumns": 
                [
                    {"sTitle": "Name", "mData": "name"},
                    {"sTitle": "Course", "mData": "course"},
                    {"sTitle": "Fee", "mData": "fee"},
                ]
            });

        },

        error: function (xhr) {
            console.log('Request Status: ' + xhr.status  );
            console.log('Status Text: ' + xhr.statusText );
            console.log(xhr.responseText);
            var text = $($.parseHTML(xhr.responseText)).filter('.trace-message').text();
        }

    });
```

}
**details.jsp**

```
    <%@page import="org.json.simple.JSONArray"%>
<%@page import="org.json.simple.JSONObject"%>
<%@page import="org.json.simple.parser.JSONParser"%>
<%@page import="org.json.simple.parser.ParseException"%>
<%@page contentType="text/html" pageEncoding="UTF-8"%>
<%@page import="java.sql.*" %>
 <%
    JSONObject obj = new JSONObject();
     JSONArray list = new JSONArray();
    Connection con;
    PreparedStatement pst;
    ResultSet rs;
    Class.forName("com.mysql.jdbc.Driver");
    con = DriverManager.getConnection("jdbc:mysql://localhost/studcrud", "root","");
    String query="select * from records";  
    Statement stmt=con.createStatement();
    rs=stmt.executeQuery(query);
    while(rs.next())       
{    
    String id     = rs.getString("id");
    String name   = rs.getString("name");
    String course = rs.getString("course");
    String fee    = rs.getString("fee"); 
    obj.put("name", name);
    obj.put("course", course);
    obj.put("fee", fee);
    obj.put("id", id);

    list.add(obj);
}
    out.print(list.toJSONString());
    out.flush();      

 %>
```

Comment: Try without `toJSONString()` and see if you get `json` as response or not.

Comment: if i try like that  out.print(list); it is says errors cannot find the symbols and there is no ajax respones sir

Comment: Here change this `list.put(obj);` to `list.add(obj);` ,also did you add `jar` file ?

Comment: which jar file sir need to add

Comment: check [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13155200/org-json-simple-cannot-be-resolved) or [this](http://www.java2s.com/Code/Jar/j/Downloadjsonsimple11jar.htm) you can download it

Comment: sir. i added the jar. file no error on the program when i run no data passing through ajax response i see error on console. i added above please check sir

Comment: Remove this `<% Class.forName("com.mysql.jdbc.Driver"); %>` you have declare that `2` times  in your code , also `PWC6199: Generated servlet error:
';' expected` it is on which line ?

Comment: ya removed line sir . i think may be the problem of this line out.print(list.toJSONString()); indicate the error of list

Comment: out.print(list.add(obj)); if i written like this it pass the error cannot find the symbol

Comment: [cannot find the symbol](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25706216/what-does-a-cannot-find-symbol-compilation-error-mean) check this , it might help you to solve that , i think the problem here is you have not imported `jar` correctly .

Comment: i downlaod all jar files to the library json-simple-1.1.jar

Comment: and added sir. but i don't why it is not working

Comment: sir json-simple-1.1.jar library. i imported sir. can you give you email id i send the code to you

Comment: sir now it is working output passing [{"name":"ramlangam","bal":"3077"}]  like this json thn how to pass the values into relvent textboxs

Comment: sir there how to pass this json [{"name":"ramlangam","bal":"3077"}] data to relavent textboxs  i tried like this  $("#name").val(msg[0].name); but not working

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to parse `json` in ajax `success` function i.e :

```
<script language="javascript">
   function ClickMe_Click(){
    $.ajax({

        type: "post",
        url: "details.jsp",
        data: {"a": $("#accno").val()},
        success: function(msg) {
    //parsing json response
            var obj = JSON.parse(msg); 
              alert(obj[0].bal);

                 //setting value in input field

                  $("#bal").val(obj[0].bal);
                 $("#name").val(obj[0].name);
        },
        error:function (xhr, ajaxOptions, thrownError){
            alert(xhr.status);
            alert(thrownError);
        }  
    });
    return false;
}
</script>
```

Comment: `alert(obj)` and see what it has ,also is there any error in `console` ?

Comment: sit localhost says 404 and not found . alert msg

Comment: when did you got this `[{"name":"ramlangam","bal":"3077"}]`  then as you said in comments above ,nothing is coming from jsp page ?

Comment: yes i got this ealiar. out. when you edit the code i just copied and paste it. i won't work sir,

Comment: simply i wrote success: function(msg) {


            $("#bal").val(msg[0].bal);
             $("#name").val(msg[0].name);

        }, like this get the out out json format [{"name":"ramlangam","bal":"3077"}] this

Comment: Now try and see , also check what does `alert` prints ,also update your question with your updated codes.

Comment: sir i another one doubt pls help this is simple

Comment: Yes asked is it related to same question or different ?

Comment: sir edited the question same thing please help me on this

Comment: sir edited the question same thing please help me on this.