# No libs directory included in Eclipse-built apk

Tags: android

I have suddenly started experiencing a problem whilst building a long standing apk (from within Eclipse) whereby there is suddenly no longer a lib directory (and jars) being included in the apk anymore. This just started happening out of the blue and I have tried just about everything I have found on assorted posts to resolve without success... deleting bin and gen dirs, multiple cleans/refreshes/IDE restarts, fix Project Properties etc

I also tried removing all the jar references from the build path to the point the project would not build, and then followed various instructions in [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1334802/how-can-i-use-external-jars-in-an-android-project) -- still no result.

I have now applied latest ADT (21) and SDK updates and still have the same problem.

HELP! Going slightly mad with this inconsistency now... what am I missing?

EDIT: After reinstalling ADT I was still experiencing the problem, but then I discovered my problem... even in the older apks, I had a libs directory but with no jar files... however the subdirs (armeabi, ...v7a etc) had somehow been emptied/purged of their .so files.  I guess if they are empty, they are just not included in the apk.

Comment: lib or libs? Do you have a libs folder in your project?

Comment: Additional note: not sure if it is relevant, but I just noticed that when I close Eclipse, delete the project's bin and gen dirs, and restart Eclipse, there is a warning in Console window "unable to write jarlist cache file"

Comment: @ A--C Using "libs" directory under project root.

Answer (score 0):

I think fastest solution is download and run ADT for Windows: http://developer.android.com/sdk/index.html#download