# How to use "thread" or "AsyncTask" to send email without showing the default email in Android

Tags: android, email, email-attachments

I'm developing an application and I want to send an email without going through the default procedure & without the user interaction.

I have the following code, but it didn't work.
I read more about the problem and I figured out that I should use "thread" or "AsyncTask ". However, I dunno how to use them exactly.

Here is the code:

MainActivity.java:

```
package com.example.dialup;

import android.os.Bundle;
import android.app.Activity;
import android.view.Menu;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.Button;

import android.util.Log;


public class MainActivity extends Activity {

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);



         final Button send = (Button) this.findViewById(R.id.send);
            send.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

                public void onClick(View v) {
                    // TODO Auto-generated method stub

                    try {   


                        GMailSender sender = new GMailSender("username", "pass");
                        sender.sendMail("Subject",   
                                "Body",   
                                "blabla@gmail.com",   
                                "blabla@yahoo.com"); 
                        System.out.println("Email sent");

                    } catch (Exception e) {   
                        Log.e("SendMail", e.getMessage(), e);   
                    } 

                }
            });} }
```

JSSEProvider.java

```
package com.example.dialup;


import java.security.AccessController;
import java.security.Provider;

public final class JSSEProvider extends Provider {

    public JSSEProvider() {
        super("HarmonyJSSE", 1.0, "Harmony JSSE Provider");
        AccessController.doPrivileged(new java.security.PrivilegedAction<Void>() {
            public Void run() {
                put("SSLContext.TLS",
                        "org.apache.harmony.xnet.provider.jsse.SSLContextImpl");
                put("Alg.Alias.SSLContext.TLSv1", "TLS");
                put("KeyManagerFactory.X509",
                        "org.apache.harmony.xnet.provider.jsse.KeyManagerFactoryImpl");
                put("TrustManagerFactory.X509",
                        "org.apache.harmony.xnet.provider.jsse.TrustManagerFactoryImpl");
                return null;
            }
        });
    }
}
```

GMailSender.java

```
package com.example.dialup;


import javax.activation.DataHandler;   
import javax.activation.DataSource;   
import javax.mail.Message;   
import javax.mail.PasswordAuthentication;   
import javax.mail.Session;   
import javax.mail.Transport;   
import javax.mail.internet.InternetAddress;   
import javax.mail.internet.MimeMessage;   
import java.io.ByteArrayInputStream;   
import java.io.IOException;   
import java.io.InputStream;   
import java.io.OutputStream;   
import java.security.Security;   
import java.util.Properties;   

public class GMailSender extends javax.mail.Authenticator  {   
    private String mailhost = "smtp.gmail.com";   
    private String user;   
    private String password;   
    private Session session;   

    static {   
        Security.addProvider(new com.example.dialup.JSSEProvider());   
    }  

    public  GMailSender(String user, String password)  {   




        this.user = user;   
        this.password = password;   

        Properties props = new Properties();   
        props.setProperty("mail.transport.protocol", "smtp");   
        props.setProperty("mail.host", mailhost);   
        props.put("mail.smtp.auth", "true");   
        props.put("mail.smtp.port", "465");   
        props.put("mail.smtp.socketFactory.port", "465");   
        props.put("mail.smtp.socketFactory.class",   
                "javax.net.ssl.SSLSocketFactory");   
        props.put("mail.smtp.socketFactory.fallback", "false");   
        props.setProperty("mail.smtp.quitwait", "false");   

        session = Session.getDefaultInstance(props, this);   
    }   

    protected PasswordAuthentication getPasswordAuthentication() {   
        return new PasswordAuthentication(user, password);   
    }   

    public synchronized void sendMail(String subject, String body, String sender, String recipients) throws Exception {   
        try{
        MimeMessage message = new MimeMessage(session);   
        DataHandler handler = new DataHandler(new ByteArrayDataSource(body.getBytes(), "text/plain"));   
        message.setSender(new InternetAddress(sender));   
        message.setSubject(subject);   
        message.setDataHandler(handler);   
        if (recipients.indexOf(',') > 0)   
            message.setRecipients(Message.RecipientType.TO, InternetAddress.parse(recipients));   
        else  
            message.setRecipient(Message.RecipientType.TO, new InternetAddress(recipients));   
        Transport.send(message);   
        }catch(Exception e){

        }
    }   

    public class ByteArrayDataSource implements DataSource {   
        private byte[] data;   
        private String type;   

        public ByteArrayDataSource(byte[] data, String type) {   
            super();   
            this.data = data;   
            this.type = type;   
        }   

        public ByteArrayDataSource(byte[] data) {   
            super();   
            this.data = data;   
        }   

        public void setType(String type) {   
            this.type = type;   
        }   

        public String getContentType() {   
            if (type == null)   
                return "application/octet-stream";   
            else  
                return type;   
        }   

        public InputStream getInputStream() throws IOException {   
            return new ByteArrayInputStream(data);   
        }   

        public String getName() {   
            return "ByteArrayDataSource";   
        }   

        public OutputStream getOutputStream() throws IOException {   
            throw new IOException("Not Supported");   
        }   
    }   
}
```

and here is the LogCat

```
12-27 13:33:46.589: E/Trace(8410): error opening trace file: No such file or directory (2)
12-27 13:33:46.729: E/SensorManager(8410): thread start
12-27 13:33:46.729: D/SensorManager(8410): registerListener :: handle = 0  name= LSM330DLC 3-axis Accelerometer delay= 200000 Listener= android.view.OrientationEventListener$SensorEventListenerImpl@42bfd9b8
12-27 13:33:46.739: D/SensorManager(8410): unregisterListener::  Listener= android.view.OrientationEventListener$SensorEventListenerImpl@42bfd9b8
12-27 13:33:46.739: D/Sensors(8410): Remain listener = Sending .. normal delay 200ms
12-27 13:33:46.739: I/Sensors(8410): sendDelay --- 200000000
12-27 13:33:46.739: D/SensorManager(8410): JNI - sendDelay
12-27 13:33:46.739: I/SensorManager(8410): Set normal delay = true
12-27 13:33:46.754: D/SensorManager(8410): registerListener :: handle = 0  name= LSM330DLC 3-axis Accelerometer delay= 200000 Listener= android.view.OrientationEventListener$SensorEventListenerImpl@42bfd9b8
12-27 13:33:46.784: D/libEGL(8410): loaded /system/lib/egl/libEGL_mali.so
12-27 13:33:46.789: D/libEGL(8410): loaded /system/lib/egl/libGLESv1_CM_mali.so
12-27 13:33:46.794: D/libEGL(8410): loaded /system/lib/egl/libGLESv2_mali.so
12-27 13:33:46.799: D/(8410): Device driver API match
12-27 13:33:46.799: D/(8410): Device driver API version: 10
12-27 13:33:46.799: D/(8410): User space API version: 10 
12-27 13:33:46.799: D/(8410): mali: REVISION=Linux-r2p4-02rel0 BUILD_DATE=Fri Sep 28 10:42:56 KST 2012 
12-27 13:33:46.834: D/OpenGLRenderer(8410): Enabling debug mode 0
12-27 13:34:04.184: D/SensorManager(8410): unregisterListener::  Listener= android.view.OrientationEventListener$SensorEventListenerImpl@42bfd9b8
12-27 13:34:04.184: D/Sensors(8410): Remain listener = Sending .. normal delay 200ms
12-27 13:34:04.184: I/Sensors(8410): sendDelay --- 200000000
12-27 13:34:04.184: D/SensorManager(8410): JNI - sendDelay
12-27 13:34:04.184: I/SensorManager(8410): Set normal delay = true
12-27 13:34:06.034: D/SensorManager(8410): registerListener :: handle = 0  name= LSM330DLC 3-axis Accelerometer delay= 200000 Listener= android.view.OrientationEventListener$SensorEventListenerImpl@42bfd9b8
12-27 13:34:37.794: D/SensorManager(8410): unregisterListener::  Listener= android.view.OrientationEventListener$SensorEventListenerImpl@42bfd9b8
12-27 13:34:37.794: D/Sensors(8410): Remain listener = Sending .. normal delay 200ms
12-27 13:34:37.794: I/Sensors(8410): sendDelay --- 200000000
12-27 13:34:37.794: D/SensorManager(8410): JNI - sendDelay
12-27 13:34:37.794: I/SensorManager(8410): Set normal delay = true
12-27 13:34:37.924: D/SensorManager(8410): registerListener :: handle = 0  name= LSM330DLC 3-axis Accelerometer delay= 200000 Listener= android.view.OrientationEventListener$SensorEventListenerImpl@42c3a088
12-27 13:34:37.944: D/dalvikvm(8410): GC_CONCURRENT freed 190K, 7% free 12382K/13191K, paused 3ms+13ms, total 35ms
12-27 13:34:37.954: D/SensorManager(8410): unregisterListener::  Listener= android.view.OrientationEventListener$SensorEventListenerImpl@42c3a088
12-27 13:34:37.954: D/Sensors(8410): Remain listener = Sending .. normal delay 200ms
12-27 13:34:37.954: I/Sensors(8410): sendDelay --- 200000000
12-27 13:34:37.954: D/SensorManager(8410): JNI - sendDelay
12-27 13:34:37.954: I/SensorManager(8410): Set normal delay = true
12-27 13:34:37.959: W/IInputConnectionWrapper(8410): showStatusIcon on inactive InputConnection
12-27 13:34:37.964: D/SensorManager(8410): registerListener :: handle = 0  name= LSM330DLC 3-axis Accelerometer delay= 200000 Listener= android.view.OrientationEventListener$SensorEventListenerImpl@42c3a088
12-27 13:34:38.069: W/IInputConnectionWrapper(8410): getSelectedText on inactive InputConnection
12-27 13:34:38.074: W/IInputConnectionWrapper(8410): setComposingText on inactive InputConnection
12-27 13:34:45.439: D/SensorManager(8410): unregisterListener::  Listener= android.view.OrientationEventListener$SensorEventListenerImpl@42c3a088
12-27 13:34:45.439: D/Sensors(8410): Remain listener = Sending .. normal delay 200ms
12-27 13:34:45.439: I/Sensors(8410): sendDelay --- 200000000
12-27 13:34:45.439: D/SensorManager(8410): JNI - sendDelay
12-27 13:34:45.439: I/SensorManager(8410): Set normal delay = true
12-27 13:34:45.504: W/IInputConnectionWrapper(8410): getSelectedText on inactive InputConnection
12-27 13:34:45.504: W/IInputConnectionWrapper(8410): setComposingText on inactive InputConnection
12-27 13:35:01.614: W/IInputConnectionWrapper(8410): showStatusIcon on inactive InputConnection
12-27 13:35:01.874: D/SensorManager(8410): registerListener :: handle = 0  name= LSM330DLC 3-axis Accelerometer delay= 200000 Listener= android.view.OrientationEventListener$SensorEventListenerImpl@42c184e8
12-27 13:35:01.924: D/SensorManager(8410): unregisterListener::  Listener= android.view.OrientationEventListener$SensorEventListenerImpl@42c184e8
12-27 13:35:01.924: D/Sensors(8410): Remain listener = Sending .. normal delay 200ms
12-27 13:35:01.924: I/Sensors(8410): sendDelay --- 200000000
12-27 13:35:01.944: D/SensorManager(8410): JNI - sendDelay
12-27 13:35:01.944: I/SensorManager(8410): Set normal delay = true
12-27 13:35:01.954: D/SensorManager(8410): registerListener :: handle = 0  name= LSM330DLC 3-axis Accelerometer delay= 200000 Listener= android.view.OrientationEventListener$SensorEventListenerImpl@42c184e8
```

So how can I use "thread" or "AsyncTask "  to make it work?

Comment: why you want to use an async task for it.?

Comment: because the code is not working with me. I'm pressing the send button but i didn't get the email.
& I thought about threads because it is related to network.

Comment: No, you dont need to create any separate thread or async task to send a mail.

Comment: Check that whether you are entering correct username, password and recipient address.

Comment: yes I'm entering the correct username and password but I'm not getting any email. So there is nothing wrong with the code?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use this code in android AsyncTask doInBackground method.

```
                try {   


                    GMailSender sender = new GMailSender("username", "pass");
                    sender.sendMail("Subject",   
                            "Body",   
                            "blabla@gmail.com",   
                            "blabla@yahoo.com"); 
                    System.out.println("Email sent");

                } catch (Exception e) {   
                    Log.e("SendMail", e.getMessage(), e);   
                }
```

Comment: So i should create a new class that extends AsyncTask and has doInBackground method?

Comment: The params, progress & result should be like this AsyncTask<Void, Void, Void>?

Answer (score 0):

First check whether you have added the `Internet` permission in the manifest.

Then check if you have added 3 jars found to your Android Project

If you dont have these jars, you can doenload it from here.

- [mail.jar](http://javamail-android.googlecode.com/files/mail.jar)
- [activation.jar](http://javamail-android.googlecode.com/files/activation.jar)
- [additionnal.jar](http://javamail-android.googlecode.com/files/additionnal.jar)

[Click here - How to add External Jars](https://stackoverflow.com/a/6859020/28557)

Comment: yes, I have them all and I already added the permission to my manifest

Comment: Did you get anything in the catch block, where you are sending the mail. Also at which device you are testing the app. I also have some problems with such kind of an app in devices above android4.0

Comment: I'm using Galaxy S3, no I'm not getting anything in the catch block. So this may not work on my device?

Comment: What android version is Galaxy S3.?

Comment: it was originally 4.0.4 but they released 4.1.2 and as I remember, I installed it.

Comment: Try to install and test your application in some smaller version like android2.2. If it works fine there, then it is some compatibility issue and if it doesn't work there also, then I will look at it again.