# How to call x.jar file and execute through android code

Tags: android, jar

I already added the x.jar file in android application(selecting in build path as a x.jar), But I am not able to run and call x.jar file in the application. How can I call the x.jar file?

Answer (score 0):

If this .jar is a library you should put it in the libs folder than call the ADD TO BUILD PATH.

To use the .jar file you just need to use the import and be happy.

Comment: Already I did it not working and by importing also not working any simple example so that i can follow

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1334802/how-can-i-use-external-jars-in-an-android-project

Answer (score 0):

If you need to call the file from jar which you have attached through build in path android

You just call the file like below:

For example, you attached the ksoap jar file in to your project. you call the files like,

```
 SoapObject request = new SoapObject(NAMESPACE, METHOD_NAME);
```

That is you call file with parameters and import the class from jar that's it..