# Android:External Jar classes not found

Tags: android, jar, executable-jar

I am trying to use an external library: [Musicg Library](http://code.google.com/p/musicg/).

It is an android compatible library as they claim.

Now I followed all the instructions in [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1334802/how-can-i-use-external-jars-in-an-android-project?lq=1) to import the jar into the android project but it doesn't recognize the classes defined the jar file.

Also I tried to follow various other posts but most of the posts are referring to keep the jar in libs folder which I have done already.

Moreover I have checked that the class inside the jar is public.

Can somebody help me in solving this problem?
Any help will be appreciated! :)

EDIT

I have already kept the .jar in the libs folder.And I couldn't resolve the problem.

Comment: Is it a build error or runtime error? What is the exact message?

Answer (score 0):

You need to put the `.jar` file in a `libs/` folder at the root of your Android project (at the same level as your `AndroidManifest.xml`.