# How to import Mapsforge library source into Eclipse

Tags: android, eclipse, import, android-library

I'm kinda new to using libraries and would like to seek some basic help here.

I've been trying to use Mapsforge's .jar library here: https://code.google.com/p/mapsforge/downloads/list, however it seems like the .jar file is extremely outdated, and they seem to have only updated their stuff on their source codes in some git repository.

I've been directed to here: https://code.google.com/p/mapsforge/source/checkout, where I seem to be able to get the most updated codes. However I have no idea how to import this as a library into my eclipse for my own usage. It doesn't seem to be as simple as copy/paste a .jar file in the lib folder.

Can anyone give me a rough guide on how to do this step by step so that I am able to use the updated codes? I'm not really familiar with this git repository thing.

Thank you!

Answer (score 3):

are you using linux? then:

Step 1: install git & maven (i.e. in shell "su -c 'pacman -S maven git'")

Step 2.1: create folder where to store git repositories  (i.e. in shell "mkdir ~/Documents/git")

Step 2.2: use shell to go to an arbitrary folder (i.e. in shell "cd ~/Documents/git")

Step 3: check out the repository (in shell "git clone https://code.google.com/p/mapsforge/source/checkout" )

Step 4: go into the mapsforge directory (i.e. cd ~/Documents/git/mapsforge)

Step 5: in shell enter "mvn clean && mvn install"

Step 6: jar should now be in  path_to_mapsforge//mapsforge-map/target/ (i.e. ~/Documents/git/mapsforge/mapsforge-map/target/ )

Step 7: create folder libs in your application that needs the lib (i.e. ~/Documents/workspace/AdvancedMapViewer/libs )

Step 8: copy mapsforge-map-0.3.1-SNAPSHOT-jar-with-dependencies.jar to mentioned directory

Step 9: in eclipse click right on project and select refresh

Step 10: in eclipse right click on project -> select build path -> configure build path

Step 12: in libraries delete entry that contains name of the jar

Step 11: in libraries select add jar and select mentioned jar

now it should work...

Answer (score 0):

Just build mapsforge sources in a separate java project in order to get a jar and import it to your Android project.

In your project to build your jar be carefull to follow JDK 1.6 coding rules. Set Java Compiler -> JDK Compliance -> 1.6 (1.5 if you use older Android SDK 2.x, API 10 and lower)

To import a jar to your Android project:
https://stackoverflow.com/a/6859020/891479

Don't forget to import also the dependencies library if needed. For the logging you could need to import also slf4j-android-1.x.x.jar.