# Still Gets "Couldn't get connection factory client" Error

Tags: android, google-maps, google-maps-android-api-2

04-01 10:17:20.701: E/MapActivity(377): Couldn't get connection factory client

All I get is gray tiles and the map doesn't get loaded.

Hey everyone I know there are lots of similar posts I did thoroughly go through them.

It can be Internet permission (I added that before application tag ), Or

uses-library android:name="com.google.android.maps" (Added inside application tag ) or

it's bad API Key.

Here's the thing I earlier created a debug key and Google map api v1 displayed map correctly with no problem.
Later when i opened that project it didn't resolve MapActivity,GeoPoint,MapController etc..

so I created another debug key which I'm using now on this project and I double checked I followed all the steps correctly when creating api.

Is this(me creating a new debug over old) causing this problem? Should I delete the debug.keystore in C:\Users\abc.android and debug the project to automatically create a new? would it solve the problem or will it lead me to more problems?

I've been searching for a solution since yesterday I still have the problem please help me.Thank you so much in advance if any code is needed let me know I'll post them.

MActivity.java

```
package com.Aws0mEKCkreaTi0ns.GlobAlpSystracKerKC;

import com.google.android.maps.GeoPoint;
import com.google.android.maps.MapActivity;
import com.google.android.maps.MapController;
import com.google.android.maps.MapView;


import android.os.Bundle;

public class MActivity extends MapActivity {


    MapController mControl;
    GeoPoint GeoP;
    MapView mapV;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.map);

        mapV =(MapView)findViewById(R.id.mapView);
        mapV.displayZoomControls(true);
        mapV.setBuiltInZoomControls(true);

        double lat = 6.796396;
        double longi = 79.877823;

        mControl = mapV.getController();

        GeoP = new GeoPoint((int)( lat * 1E6 ),(int)( longi * 1E6 ));
        mControl.animateTo(GeoP);
        mControl.setZoom(13);


    }

    @Override
    protected boolean isRouteDisplayed() {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        return false;
    }

}
```

---

map.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:background="@color/layoutbg"
    android:orientation="vertical" >

   <com.google.android.maps.MapView
        android:id="@+id/mapView"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="fill_parent"
        android:apiKey="AIzaSyCy32DkrrrrT-UBhoT8xiAW182qUaAqi3s"
        android:enabled="true"
        android:clickable="true" />

</RelativeLayout>
```

---

Manifest

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    package="com.Aws0mEKCkreaTi0ns.GlobAlpSystracKerKC"
    android:versionCode="1"
    android:versionName="1.0" >

    <uses-sdk
        android:minSdkVersion="10"
        android:targetSdkVersion="17"/>


     <permission
          android:name="com.Aws0mEKCkreaTi0ns.GlobAlpSystracKerKC.permission.MAPS_RECEIVE"
          android:protectionLevel="signature"/>
        <uses-permission android:name="com.Aws0mEKCkreaTi0ns.GlobAlpSystracKerKC.permission.MAPS_RECEIVE"/>


    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET"/>

    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE"/>
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE"/>
    <uses-permission android:name="com.google.android.providers.gsf.permission.READ_GSERVICES"/>

    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION"/>
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION"/>

    <uses-feature
        android:glEsVersion="0x00020000"
        android:required="true"/>    



    <application
        android:allowBackup="true"
        android:icon="@drawable/ic_launcher"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:theme="@style/AppTheme" >

        <uses-library android:name="com.google.android.maps" />


        <activity
            android:name="com.Aws0mEKCkreaTi0ns.GlobAlpSystracKerKC.MainActivity"
            android:label="@string/app_name" >
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>


        <activity
            android:name="com.Aws0mEKCkreaTi0ns.GlobAlpSystracKerKC.MenuActivity"
            android:label="@string/app_name" >
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="com.Aws0mEKCkreaTi0ns.GlobAlpSystracKerKC.KCLOGO" />

                <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>


        <activity
            android:name="com.Aws0mEKCkreaTi0ns.GlobAlpSystracKerKC.AddFromContactsActivity"
            android:label="@string/app_name" >
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="com.Aws0mEKCkreaTi0ns.GlobAlpSystracKerKC.ADDFROMCONTACT" />

                <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>


        <activity
            android:name="com.Aws0mEKCkreaTi0ns.GlobAlpSystracKerKC.MActivity"
            android:label="@string/app_name" >
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="com.Aws0mEKCkreaTi0ns.GlobAlpSystracKerKC.MAPS" />

                <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>


        <activity
            android:name="com.Aws0mEKCkreaTi0ns.GlobAlpSystracKerKC.LoginActivity"
            android:label="@string/app_name" >
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="com.Aws0mEKCkreaTi0ns.GlobAlpSystracKerKC.LOGIN" />

                <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>


        <activity
            android:name="com.Aws0mEKCkreaTi0ns.GlobAlpSystracKerKC.SignupActivity"
            android:label="@string/app_name" >
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="com.Aws0mEKCkreaTi0ns.GlobAlpSystracKerKC.SIGNUP" />

                <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>


        <activity
            android:name="com.Aws0mEKCkreaTi0ns.GlobAlpSystracKerKC.AddToContactsActivity"
            android:label="@string/app_name" >
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="com.Aws0mEKCkreaTi0ns.GlobAlpSystracKerKC.ADDTOCONTACTS" />

                <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>

        <meta-data
        android:name="com.google.android.maps.v2.API_KEY"
        android:value="AIzaSyCy32DkrrrrT-UBhoT8xiAW182qUaAqi3s"/>

    </application>



</manifest>
```

Comment: Are you using debug key for API 2 and using MapActivity in your code ? If you are working with API 2, you may need to update your code as well. Post some code here.

Comment: hi @DivyaMotiwala thank you for the quick reply.Yeah earlier I used Fragment to display map and I had a force close and I got to know that I can still use map View and display the map so I switched back to using mapActivity.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I guess you have mixed some of V1 and V2 features (like using `<uses-library android:name="com.google.android.maps" />` in manifest and use of `GeoPoint` etc. (**https://groups.google.com/forum/?fromgroups=#!topic/android-developers/CGF5X1HMLuY**)

Try with the sample code below :

MActivity.java

```
   public class MActivity extends FragmentActivity{

private GoogleMap map;
    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_map);

        map = ((SupportMapFragment) getSupportFragmentManager().findFragmentById(R.id.map))
                .getMap();

        double lat = 6.796396;
        double longi = 79.877823;
        final LatLng HAMBURG = new LatLng(lat,longi);
        Marker hamburg = map.addMarker(new MarkerOptions().position(HAMBURG)
                .title("Hamburg"));
        map.moveCamera(CameraUpdateFactory.newLatLngZoom(HAMBURG, 15));


    }
```

Map.xml

```
   <RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
tools:context=".MapsActivity" >

<fragment
    android:id="@+id/map"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    class="com.google.android.gms.maps.SupportMapFragment" />
  </RelativeLayout>
```

Remove `<uses-library android:name="com.google.android.maps" />`
 from manifest.

Comment: hey thanx for the reply I tried what you suggested but I get "can't be resolved to type" error on 'GoogleMap' & 'SupportMapFragment' I did add google-play-services_lib file->import->existing android into workspace and Project->properties->android->add->google-play-services_lib when i first add library reference it shows that green tick sign but when I close it and again go to Project->properties->android that added google-play-services_lib is shown as red cross mark is that the issue?

Comment: Yeah..i guess its not imported properly.You should be referencing a copy of the library that you copied to your source tree, you should not reference the library from the Android SDK directory (say Copy project into workspace while importing) .You also need to add `google-support-v4` library for `SupportMapFragment`.

Comment: google-support-v4.jar is already in the lib folder... I'll try the referencing again and let you know thank you.

Comment: Thank you so much  for your time & effort appreciate it.

Comment: I'll choose your answer as accepted since you pointed me to use SupportFragmentManager on the first place. :)

Answer (score 1):

Running google map v2 on emulator has several steps, so I prepared step by step tutorial to show how you can use google map android v2 on emulator(android 4.2.2) have a look at to my blog: http://umut.tekguc.info/en/content/google-android-map-v2-step-step

Comment: Thank you so much  for your time & effort appreciate it

Answer (score 0):

Actually I've been adding a different project's .jar file & [This](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1334802/how-can-i-use-external-jars-in-an-android-project) helped me to correctly add a external .jar to the project.Now I don't get "unresolved type" error.. Thank you everyone for pointing me to the correct direction you people are awesome.