# can't start google maps "couldn't get connection factory client" in logcat

Tags: android

I have added the following in my manifest:

```
 <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />
  <uses-library android:name="com.google.android.maps"/>
```

and I also added apikey in my layout:

```
 <com.google.android.maps.MapView
   android:layout_width="fill_parent"
   android:layout_height="fill_parent"
   android:apiKey="yjguihjoXkojihgfdcfhgvyjhkjh"
   android:id="@+id/mvMain"
   android:enabled="true"
   android:clickable="true"
   />
```

But I can not see the map, I can only see the grid boxes and in the log cat the following statement shows up:

```
"couldn't get connection factory client"
```

. Whats the problem.I appreciate any assistance.

Comment: Which version of Google Map are you using?

Answer (score 0):

You are using Google Map V1 in your XML which is deprecated and in your Android Manifest you wrote code for Google Map V2

Change your XML file as follows

```
<fragment xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:id="@+id/map"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
class="com.google.android.gms.maps.SupportMapFragment"/>
```

and remove

```
<uses-library android:name="com.google.android.maps" />
```

Check out the [tutorial](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/android/)

You can also refer [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15737960/still-gets-couldnt-get-connection-factory-client-error)