# MonkeyRunner and MySQL

Tags: mysql, jython, monkeyrunner

I got a problem using MySQL with MonkeyRunner, need a help with MySQL Driver Name. The starting of my script is:

```
#coding : utf-8

from com.android.monkeyrunner import MonkeyRunner,MonkeyDevice
from com.ziclix.python.sql import zxJDBC

db = zxJDBC.connect('jdbc:mysql://localhost/android','dani','123456','com.mysql.jdbc.Driver')
.
.
etc
```

Each time I got an error that **com.mysql.jdbc.Driver** not found even when using **org.git.mm.mysql.Driver**. I set classpath as following :

```
export CLASSPATH=$CLASSPATH:/usr/share/java/mysql-connector-java.5.1.10.jar
```

Any tips or hits?

Regards,,,

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to include the relevant jar in the correct location.  There should be a libs folder where you need to put the jar.  It should be in the top level of your project folder, at the same level as the src and res folders.

Comment: You mean if my project in /home/..../Project
The I need to create a file /home/..../Project/lib and put that jar inside?

Comment: Take a look at the top answer here, it explains where to put the jar http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1334802/how-can-i-use-external-jars-in-an-android-project