# Scala Jar (Goose), how to use directly in Android/Java

Tags: java, android, scala, goose

can anybody help?
I used to use Goose to extra text from html to complete. I've imported in my project and try to run, but the exception comes

> 07-18 09:44:13.472: E/AndroidRuntime(2565): Caused by:
>   java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: com.gravity.goose.Goose

I think it might be a problem between Java and Scala.

code like:

```
    String url = mNewsItem.getURL();
    Goose goose = new Goose(new Configuration());
    Article article = goose.extractContent(url);
```

Thx

Comment: Try exporting "Android private dependencies" in the Build Path settings Dialog.

Comment: @Rekin I've done it, but it still sent the same exception. And in Eclipse I've seen the class and all methods, but only crashes at runtime.

Comment: I suspect the jar is somehow lost during the final `.dex` build. Try the steps provided here and see if that helps: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1334802/how-can-i-use-external-jars-in-an-android-project

Comment: Oh, and very important: during the udpate from Eclipse ADT <= 22 to the 22 Version the library folder name changed from "lib" to "libs".

Comment: @Rekin I think that all path configurations are correct. Because the App uses other 3rd-libs as well and I did it just like others. I think there is a problem between Scala and Java, if it was the point, what should I do?

Comment: I've no more ideas - try changing the question and tags to make it more obvious it's about scala. Maybe someone with the necessary knowledge would then see it.

Comment: @Rekin Thanks a lot. At end I found a new version of lib and just replaced the old one, it runs.

Comment: @TeeTracker: Are you packaging this with Proguard? It might strip the class out.