# JOrtho implemention

Tags: java, eclipse

I have a program that I made on Java in eclipse which I have to add spell checking functionality using JOrtho.
However I am not able to implement it, like what do I do after I download the zip file from http://sourceforge.net/projects/jortho/files/
Please help, thank you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After you have download the zip file, unzip it and **add jortho.jar file into your java project** as library.

There are many [userful answers here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/6859020/1799322) teach you how to include .jar file to your java project. Check it out.