# I can add xmlse1.4 jar in project android?

Tags: android

I have a project I want to add the jar but I get error is  **xmlsec1.4 from apache**

Sorry for my bad English

Thanks

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1334802/how-can-i-use-external-jars-in-an-android-project

Comment: Thanks for the speed, I do all the above but the link returns the error but not against
11-14 08:41:56.312: E / AndroidRuntime (32192): java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: adsi.org.apache.xml.security.Init
11-14 08:41:56.312: E / AndroidRuntime (32192): at ...

Comment: the  library xmlsec1.4.2,  same library I've tasted in a Java project and work and now wanted to use in a project for signing android xml
sorry for my bad English

Answer (score 0):

I think problem that you put error jar file.
It should be something like this: xmlsec-1.4.4.jar

Check this link: http://www.java2s.com/Code/Jar/x/Downloadxmlsec144jar.htm