# Android Gson no classDef found

Tags: android, gson

i need a help with using Gson library. I made a build path and imported it into my class, but when i initialize the Gson object i get an NoClassDefFoundError. I also tryed to download some other versions but didnt helped. Now using 2.2.4.
Thanks in advance!

Comment: Are you using AndroidStudio?

Comment: Make sure you add external jar like [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1334802/how-can-i-use-external-jars-in-an-android-project?lq=1)

Comment: i did but it dont work...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this

1. Right click on project
2. Properties
3. Java Build Path
4. Order And Export
5. Check all dependencies
6. Clean and Build
7. Now Run your project

[image: add Gson to project]

Answer (score 0):

Here is a guide that could help you. Its explains how to setup and use GSON.

[Use GSON to work with JSON in your Android apps](http://www.techrepublic.com/blog/software-engineer/use-gson-to-work-with-json-in-your-android-apps/)

Answer (score 0):

To add support of GSON on android studio, just add line below to app build.gradle file.

```
compile 'com.google.code.gson:gson:2.7'
```

By now 2.7 is last current available version according to: https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/com.google.code.gson/gson

Please check this repository to be sure you are using last available version.