# Calling a method from library (jar)

Tags: android

I'm trying to understand library usage in Android. So I created a very simple library and import it in my project. I want to call the method **cubeOf()** from **MyOperations.jar** (library file). There is no building errors but the application is stopping unexpectedly when I runned.

**MainActivity.java** class (in MyApplication):

```
package com.sam.myapplication;

import android.app.Activity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.Menu;
import android.widget.TextView;
import com.sam.mylibrary.MyOperations;

public class MainActivity extends Activity {

    TextView tv1;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        tv1 = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.textView1);
        MyOperations op = new MyOperations();
        int a = op.cubeOf(8); // Just a random number
        tv1.setText(a);
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
        getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.main, menu);
        return true;
    }
}
```

**MyOperations.java** class (in MyLibrary):

```
package com.sam.mylibrary;

public class MyOperations {
    public static void main(String[] arg) {

    }
    public static int cubeOf(int i) {
        int c = i*i*i;
        return c;
    }
}
```

#### **SOLVED!**

Thanks for replies, I solved the issue through [**this article**](http://www.vogella.com/articles/AndroidLibraryProjects/article.html).

Comment: cubeOf being a static method should be accessed in a static way: MyOperations.cubeOf().

Comment: @GoranHoriaMihail I edited but still same problem.

Comment: If the app's crashing, you should have a stack trace of some kind in your console; that should help you find the problem—if it doesn't, post it here as more information.

Comment: @SpacePope Thanks for advice I added my log errors to the post.

Answer (score 0):

Change

```
    tv1.setText(a);
```

with

```
 tv1.setText(String.valueOf(a));
```

in your case you are using `a` as index for R.string, and if it does not exist, `ResourceNotFoundException` will be thrown

Comment: Thanks but nothing changed.

Answer (score 0):

You are not mentioning the reason for your application to crash. I believe there might be 2 problems:

## 1 adding to blackbelt answer above:

you might simply use:

put setText(""+a)

So there isn't confusion about 'a' being used as numeric vs. string

## 2 You may have a build path issue.

Look at this answer:

[How can I use external JARs in an Android project?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1334802/how-can-i-use-external-jars-in-an-android-project)

If you have a pretty recent version of Eclipse/ADT the folder should be called 'libs' else the folder was called 'lib' ( Eclipse/ADT TBD )

Also, the "Java Build Path" -> "Order And Export" make sure you are checking on the external library especially if from a different package.

Comment: I have already built the path, and yes i'm using a recent version.

Comment: Did you checked marked the library as export in the "Order And Export" tab ? Actually, are using a reference project or a compiled .jar version? Did you exported classes from the library project?

Comment: Do you have a s ky pe ac c o unt? I can offer a few minutes of support.

Answer (score 0):

So just to confirm earlier responses, you tried *both* changes in `onCreate`? That is,

```
    int a = MyOperations.cubeOf(8); // Just a random number
    tv1.setText(String.valueOf(a));
```

1. call static methods statically (don't even `new` a `MyOperations`)
2. pass a string to setText

Comment: Yes, i did both of them.