# How to reference android classes from external library

Tags: java, android

I'm working with external library. Now my android application has two projects:
"*MyAndroidApp*" and "*HelperLibrary*".
"*MyAndroidApp*" is main application project and "*HelperLibrary*" contains my model classes.   In "*HelperLibrary*", I need to implement "`android.os.Parcelable`" interface.
In fact, I can find "*Parcelable*" in "*MyAndroidApp*" project but cannot find at "*HelperLibrary*" project.
How can I add android package to "*HelperLibrary*" project?

Any helps would be very appreciated.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1334802/how-can-i-use-external-jars-in-an-android-project

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think your issue is that "HelperLibrary" is not an android library project,may be an ordinary java project.You should make it as an android library project.You just need to include an android library in its build target.Then you can import "android.os.Parcelable" .

Comment: Is it possible to add jars without add build path? If yes, where is the android built-in jars?

Comment: For reference you can find the android jar here in this location,where you have copied your sdk "\sdk\platforms\android-17"

Comment: Thansk I have found at C:\adt-bundle-windows\sdk\platforms\android-19\android.jar path. When I looked at file size its 20.7 MB. Will this file size be at the resulted apk package? If yes, how can avoid this issue?

Comment: Its not an issue it only adds the classes which you are referring from it.

Answer (score 0):

Hi please follow these ways to add library

http://www.wikihow.com/Add-JARs-to-Project-Build-Paths-in-Eclipse-(Java)

after adding the library you can call classes.

after this please have alook on api level packages and Import them as

```
import a.b.c.*;
```