# Android project jar file missing after pushing to github

Tags: android, eclipse, git, github, jar

I added the `Google Gson jar` file to my Android project by copying and pasting the `gson-2.2.4 jar` file to the `libs` folder and then **right clicked on the Jar file and then select Build Path > Add to Build Path**(I followed [this tutorial](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1334802/how-can-i-use-external-jars-in-an-android-project)). Then everything worked fine for me with this jar file, but after pushing to `github`, when my friends pulling this project, they said that all code relevant to that Gson jar file shows errors. How could I fix this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can create a `library project` which contains the `jar` file, and then add this library to your project.

Create library project in eclipse:
**File->New->Android application project->Next->Check Mark this porject as a library,
uncheck Create custom launcher icon and Create activity->Finish**

Add the library to your project:
**Right click your project->Properties->Android->Add->Select the library project you created
->Apply->OK**

After finishing these two, you should be able to use `Gson`, and when pushing your project, 
remember to push the `library project` as well.

Comment: As you said its working fine but " push the library project as well",When i try to push the library project it shows the same error...How to push the support library(gson) to github?

Answer (score 1):

Problem 1 : Jar doesnt exist. You probably forgot to add, commit and push your changes to github after adding the jar.

Problem 2 : Jar exists but unrecognised. Ask your friends to remove the existing library from java build path using project properties and add again.