# Android project cannot find third party libraries in Eclipse

Tags: java, android, eclipse

It seems that Eclipse cannot find the third party libraries being used by the app even though I see them all in the libs folder under the package.For example, it cannot find the Crittercism, Google Analytics or Parse libraries. The import statements below all show a red X and when I click on the prompt to fix the import links, it says I have to do it manually:

```
import com.crittercism.app.Crittercism;
import com.google.analytics.tracking.android.EasyTracker;
import com.google.analytics.tracking.android.MapBuilder;

import com.parse.ParseException;
import com.parse.ParseObject;
import com.parse.ParseQuery;
```

My question is, how do I force Eclipse to look in the right folder, assuming it is not looking in the right place for the libraries. This is working source code from the developer which we used to create the apk and upload it to the Google Play Store, so I assume there is no issue with the code, but more so in the way the project is configured in Eclipse.

Comment: Just to cover some basics...do you have the ADT plugin installed?

Comment: Check if the libs that show error mark have been moved to some other location. I had faced such issue. If so, fix that.

Comment: Just add remove and re-add them from libs in Java Build Path dialog.

Comment: Yes, the ADT plugin is installed. The libs folder is in the root of the package and all the third party libraries are in there so it doesn't seem they have been moved.

Comment: Can you post your `.classpath` file?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. Basic thing you can do is clean/build the project Project>Clean  (Refer Image : https://i.stack.imgur.com/T9ihk.png) and check if the things  fixed
2. Check the necessary jars are available in libs folder of you project root.
3. Check if the neccessary jars are properly added to buildpath. Right click your project  > click on Properties (Refer Image : https://i.stack.imgur.com/A6xgq.png). If you see it highlight with red then you can remove it and follow these steps (https://stackoverflow.com/a/6859020/28557) to add your jars to buildpath.