# Getting dates after certain period of time in Java

Tags: java, android, sqlite, date

Basically I have a date stored as text in this format: `16/09/2014` in SQLite Browser. I wonder is there any way to get the date after one day, one week, one month and one year of each records in the database using Java.

I retrieved and display the date retrieved from database in a listview:

```
viewHolder.txt_ddate.setText("Next Payment On: "
                + _recurlist.get(position).getRecurringStartDate().trim());
```

So I was thinking to use Java technique to get the dates I mentioned above. I have researched on this and found [Documentation](http://www.java2s.com/Tutorial/Java/0040__Data-Type/AddweektocurrentdateusingCalendaraddmethod.htm) but I not sure how to implement it into my problem.

Any guides? Thanks in advance.

Comment: no, the format should be yyyy/MM/dd (with / or without or with -) ... then the comparing of strings should act in the same way as dates comparing ... now you can do this with sqlite query with WHERE: `"data > ? AND date < ?"`and WHERE ARGS `new String[] {"2014/09/16", "2014/09/23" }` of course the date ranges should be done in Java code ... another way is to store dates as EPOCH time (integer)

Comment: Nope, I do not want to touch it with SQL statement as I am trying to do in this way: I retrieve the dates from database, then I show it depends on the frequency like for example after one day, one week and so on.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use a Calendar object like in your example, which provides the add method.

```
String dateAsString = "16/09/2014";
DateFormat formatter = new SimpleDateFormat("dd/MM/yyyy");
Calendar c = Calendar.getInstance();
c.setTime(formatter.parse(dateAsString));

c.add(Calendar.DAY_OF_MONTH, 1);
System.out.println("After one day: " + formatter.format(c.getTimeInMillis()));
c.add(Calendar.DAY_OF_MONTH, -1);

c.add(Calendar.WEEK_OF_YEAR, 1);
System.out.println("After one week: " + formatter.format(c.getTimeInMillis()));
c.add(Calendar.WEEK_OF_YEAR, -1);

c.add(Calendar.MONTH, 1);
System.out.println("After one month: " + formatter.format(c.getTimeInMillis()));
c.add(Calendar.MONTH, -1);

c.add(Calendar.YEAR, 1);
System.out.println("After one year: " + formatter.format(c.getTimeInMillis()));
c.add(Calendar.YEAR, -1);
```

Output:

```
After one day: 17/09/2014
After one week: 23/09/2014
After one month: 16/10/2014
After one year: 16/09/2015
```

Comment: Why -1 after each println?

Comment: I was asked to surround it with a try catch. But after added this portion of codes, my date does not show up anymore. Any ideas?

Comment: FYI, the troublesome old date-time classes such as [`java.util.Date`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/Date.html), [`java.util.Calendar`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/Calendar.html), and `java.text.SimpleTextFormat` are now [legacy](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Legacy_system), supplanted by the [java.time](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/time/package-summary.html) classes. See [Tutorial by Oracle](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/datetime/TOC.html). See ThreeTen-Backport and ThreeTenABP projects for Android.

Answer (score 1):

With [Joda-time](http://www.joda.org/joda-time/):

```
DateTimeFormatter formatter = DateTimeFormat.forPattern("dd/MM/yyyy");
LocalDate date = LocalDate.parse("16/09/2014", formatter);

System.out.println(date.toString(formatter));
System.out.println(date.plusDays(1).toString(formatter));
System.out.println(date.plusWeeks(1).toString(formatter));
System.out.println(date.plusMonths(1).toString(formatter));
System.out.println(date.plusYears(1).toString(formatter));
```

Output:

```
16/09/2014
17/09/2014
23/09/2014
16/10/2014
16/09/2015
```

Comment: yeah, but it told me DateTimeFormatter cant resolve to a type and there's nothing to import. Any guides?

Comment: You would need to download the JARs associated with Joda-time (see link in answer) and add those to your project.

Comment: So I just download the JARs and import it into my project will do?

Comment: Well... you need to find the correct way to add JARs to your Android project. If you use Eclipse, this question might help: [How can I use external JARs in an Android project?](http://stackoverflow.com/q/1334802)

Comment: Thanks a lot! I've found another solution from other posts!

Comment: Android does not support Java-8. The only chance would be to use the Threeten-backport-project. Or using Joda-Time or Time4J?! The suggested code would have to be adjusted for those external libraries.

Comment: @Meno I'm confused - my code is for Joda not Java 8.

Comment: @Duncan Ah now I see, both libraries look sometimes very similar in code (same class name `LocalDate`) then I was myself confused, sorry.

Comment: FYI, the [Joda-Time](http://www.joda.org/joda-time/) project is now in [maintenance mode](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Maintenance_mode), with the team advising migration to the [java.time](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/time/package-summary.html) classes. See [Tutorial by Oracle](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/datetime/TOC.html).  See ThreeTen-Backport and ThreeTenABP projects for Android.

Answer (score 1):

Use Calendar api of Java/Android as follow:

```
SimpleDateFormat sdf = new SimpleDateFormat("dd/MM/yyyy");

Date date;

try {
    date = sdf.parse(dateStr);
    Calendar cal = Calendar.getInstance();
    cal.setTime(date);
    cal.add(Calendar.DAY_OF_MONTH, 1); //add one day to your date
    cal.add(Calendar.MONTH, 1); //add 1 month to your date 
    cal.add(Calendar.YEAR, 1); //add 1 year to current date
    System.out.println(sdf.format(cal.getTimeInMillis()));
} catch (ParseException e) {
    // TODO Auto-generated catch block
    e.printStackTrace();
}
```

Comment: But how do I print each dates out?

Comment: Please see edited answer. You can use same `SimpleDateFormatter sdf`

Answer (score 0):

Here is the example:

```
String strDate = "16/09/2014";
int noOfDays = 1;
SimpleDateFormat formatter = new SimpleDateFormat("dd/MM/yyyy");
Date date = formatter.parse(strDate);
Calendar cal = Calendar.getInstance();
cal.setTime(date);
cal.add(Calendar.DATE, noOfDays);
```

Comment: Thanks a lot! I found the solutions above!

Answer (score 0):

## tl;dr

```
LocalDate.parse( 
    "16/09/2014" , 
    DateTimeFormatter.ofPattern( "dd/MM/uuuu" )
)
.plusDays( 1 )
.format( DateTimeFormatter.ofPattern( "dd/MM/uuuu" ) )
```

## Details

Tip: Use date-time data types for date-time values. You should be using a date-oriented type to define your column in your database to store a date value rather than as text.

Tip # 2: When you do serialize a date value to text, use the standard [ISO 8601](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ISO_8601) formats. These are sensible, practical, and sort chronologically when alphabetical.

Use the java.time classes rather than the troublesome old date-time classes that are now legacy. For Android, see bullets below.

```
DateTimeFormatter f = DateTimeFormatter.ofPattern( "dd/MM/uuuu" ) ;
LocalDate ld = LocalDate.parse( "16/09/2014" , f ) ;

LocalDate dayAfter = ld.plusDays( 1 ) ; 
LocalDate weekAfter = ld.plusWeeks( 1 ) ;
LocalDate monthAfter = ld.plusMonths( 1 ) ;
LocalDate yearAfter = ld.plusYears( 1 ) ;
```

To generate a string in standard format, simply call `toString`.

```
String output = dayAfter.toString() ;  // YYYY-MM-DD standard format.
```

> 2014-09-17

For other formats, use a `DateTimeFormatter` as seen above.

```
String output = dayAfter.format( f ) ;
```

> 17/09/2014

---

## About java.time

The [java.time](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/time/package-summary.html) framework is built into Java 8 and later. These classes supplant the troublesome old [legacy](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Legacy_system) date-time classes such as [`java.util.Date`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/Date.html), [`Calendar`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/Calendar.html), & [`SimpleDateFormat`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/text/SimpleDateFormat.html).

The [Joda-Time](http://www.joda.org/joda-time/) project, now in [maintenance mode](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Maintenance_mode), advises migration to the [java.time](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/time/package-summary.html) classes.

To learn more, see the [Oracle Tutorial](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/datetime/TOC.html). And search Stack Overflow for many examples and explanations. Specification is [JSR 310](https://jcp.org/en/jsr/detail?id=310).

Where to obtain the java.time classes?

- [**Java SE 8**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Java_version_history#Java_SE_8), [**Java SE 9**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Java_version_history#Java_SE_9), and later

  - Built-in.
  - Part of the standard Java API with a bundled implementation.
  - Java 9 adds some minor features and fixes.
- [**Java SE 6**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Java_version_history#Java_SE_6) and [**Java SE 7**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Java_version_history#Java_SE_7)

  - Much of the java.time functionality is back-ported to Java 6 & 7 in [***ThreeTen-Backport***](http://www.threeten.org/threetenbp/).
- [**Android**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Android_(operating_system))

  - The [***ThreeTenABP***](https://github.com/JakeWharton/ThreeTenABP) project adapts *ThreeTen-Backport* (mentioned above) for Android specifically.
  - See [*How to use ThreeTenABP…*](http://stackoverflow.com/q/38922754/642706).