# Android depependency folder not found- Google glass

Tags: android, eclipse, google-glass

I have added external jars into libs folder, But they get added into android private libraries .In my build path I don't see them under android dependencies.they get added to android private libraries.Also I get an error once I close and open the properties window of my project.Please find snapshot.[image]

I have tried cleaning my project and fixing my project properties.But that doesn't help.

Here is my project.properties

```
target=Google Inc.:Glass Development Kit Preview:19
android.library.reference.1=../tess-two-master/tess-two
```

EDIT:
This issue is specific to GDK preview.For a normal android project the below answers work perfect.**I am getting this issue only in Google glass projects**.

Answer (score 1):

[From here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1334802/how-can-i-use-external-jars-in-an-android-project)

A good way to add external JARs to your Android project or any Java project is:

1. Create a folder called libs in your project's root folder
2. Copy your JAR files to the libs folder
3. Now right click on the Jar file and then select Build Path > Add to
   Build Path, which will create a folder called 'Referenced Libraries'
   within your project

By doing this, you will not lose your libraries that are being referenced on your hard drive whenever you transfer your project to another computer.

Comment: Thank you.That creates a folder android references.I want to know why Android dependencies folder is not found in my project

Comment: @PrasannaAarthi Right click on the project and select Android Tools > Fix Project Properties

Comment: I did give it a try before posting

Answer (score 0):

You can try this:

**Your Project -> right click -> Properties -> Java Build Path -> Libraries -> Add Jar -> tess-two.jar**

If that doesn't help then try referring to [**this**](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=eY_uqi_qIz0) video link.

Comment: Thank you,I tried it..I still get the error in my screenshot, that doesnt resolve..Also an absolute path will not come there, It should show up like ../tess-two

Comment: Try to import tess-two project in eclipse as a library project. And then in your main project add this as a libary by Right click on project -> Properties -> Android -> Add -> select "tess-two" -> Apply.

Comment: Yeah that is how I have done and attached the screenshot