# Can not add gson to android project properly

Tags: java, android, eclipse, gson

I am trying to use gson in my android project .So i downloaded Gson . then i did the following:

`Right click on project -> build path -> add libraries`

Now i can see that the jar file is in:

`Project -> properties -> java build path -> libraries tab`

But when I import `com.google.gson.Gson` there is an error

`"The import com.google cannot be resolved"`. com.google is underlined with red but gson.Gson is not underlined .

What am i missing ??

Thanks in advance !!

Comment: Why you don't use Gradle to add dependency?

Comment: just add gson jar into libs folder of your android project

Comment: I have just started android development . So can u please tell me how to add gson into libs folder ?

Comment: Read this link : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1334802/how-can-i-use-external-jars-in-an-android-project