# How to recover android.jar file in eclipse

Tags: android, eclipse

Hello I accidently deleted android.jar file from my eclipse project.Is there any way to get it back.As I am getting many type of errors.

Comment: possible duplicate of [How can I use external JARs in an Android project?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1334802/how-can-i-use-external-jars-in-an-android-project)

Answer (score 0):

1. right click and go to project
2. select android on the left side menu
3. uncheck and recheck the API level as needed.

This is should give you your android.jar back

Answer (score 0):

Go to Window->Android SDK Manager and install "Sources for Android SDK".

Now try to control-click some Android identify, you will get the usual "no source attached" page. Click "Attach Source" and get the option to select an external folder.

Now browse to `/home/me/android-sdks/sources/android-16` (or wherever your SDK is installed; this is the default), and hit ok.

It should think for a moment and then display the source! !

Answer (score 0):

Its very Genuine case happens with me lots of times.

Here what I did:

1. Right Click on your Project and go to properties.
2. Make Sure you Clicked Android and Now unmarked any Selected API and click "Apply"
3. Now Again Select your Desire API, latest One I guess and Click Apply Again.

Now You Should have `android.jar` file into your project.

Cheers
-Aman