# Cann't running MQTT example project on Android

Tags: java, android, mqtt

I'm a newbie in programming Android APP. I'm using ActiveMQ running on Win7 as a Messaging Server. I'm trying to test Message-Oriented Middleware protocols such as MQTT, STOMP, etc. via Android APP.

I've import adroid-mqtt-demo repo's project to Eclipse to test MQTT connection, and include the java_1.4_uber.jar from [mqtt-client](https://github.com/fusesource/mqtt-client). I encountered same problem with [this issue](https://github.com/jsherman1/android-mqtt-demo/issues/2).

So I tried to create a source folder /mqtt which is same level with /src under this project, and I copy-paste all the classes under /matt-client/src/main/java/org/fusesource/mqtt directory in the mqtt-client repo one by one. (very stupid, I know, but I don't know other way to achieve it.)

But when I ran this app on either on emulator or my android phone, it showed another errors, such as `"error opening trace file", "Could not find class 'org.fusesource.hawbuf.UTF8Buffer'", and "java.lang.VerifyError: org/fusesource/mqtt/codec/CONNECT"`.

I've googled to find out the solution for many days, and still cannot find how to make it work. Could anybody give me some advices?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you just want to run the demo you only need to download the uber-jar (as you already did) and then you need to 1) create a `libs` folder in your project's root folder 2) copy the jar file inside that folder and 3) right click on the uber-jar file, select Build Path > Add to Build Path.

The above is what user *anandaverma* describes here:https://github.com/jsherman1/android-mqtt-demo/issues/2

This should also be helpful: [How can I use external JARs in an Android project?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1334802/how-can-i-use-external-jars-in-an-android-project). As it is mentioned in one of the comments:

> Note that when using recent Eclipse/ADT versions the external jars
>   have to be in a folder called libs (instead of lib)