# Android app with 'DB2SimpleDataSource Class not found' error

Tags: java, android, eclipse, db2, ibm-cloud

I have an Android app in which I wanted to use the `DB2SimpleDataSource` class contained in the db2jcc.jar / db2jcc4.jar file. I wanted to use this class to establish a connection to a DB2 Database, but I noticed a problem with that class.
So I wrote a very simple app which just instantiate a DB2SimpleDataSource class object,in this way:

```
     import android.app.Activity;
     import android.os.Bundle;
     import android.view.Menu;
     import android.view.MenuItem;
     import com.ibm.db2.jcc.DB2SimpleDataSource;

     public class MainActivity extends Activity {

     @Override
     protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
     super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
     setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
     DB2SimpleDataSource dataSource = new DB2SimpleDataSource(); //--->Error!
     }
```

Here's the problem:when I write this code,Eclipse shows no errors about this class,but when i run this app,it shows the following error in logcat:

```
 Could not find class 'com.ibm.db2.jcc.DB2SimpleDataSource' referenced 
 from method 'com.example.provadb2.MainActivity.onCreate'
```

Here's the process I used to add the JARs:

1. Right click on project>Properties
2. From Java Build Path,in Libraries tab,i clicked "Add External JARs" and pointed to the db2jcc.jar file
3. In Order and Export tab,i checked db2jcc.jar

I also tried unchecking in the Order and Export tab but nothing happened.

I also tried to use `db2jcc4.jar` file,without results.

The "funny" thing is that,when I wrote the same code in Java instantiating a DB2SimpleDataSource class object,it worked without errors...Hope i can find some help,thanks.

Comment: you would find more help if you used gradle to build your project, rather than eclipse

Comment: i read this tutorial:http://www.ibm.com/developerworks/cloud/library/cl-mvc-mobile-bluemix-app/#N1017F in which DB2SimpleDataSource is used in Android without errors

Comment: Is the driver jar packed with your android application and available at runtime?

Comment: Could you be more specific?I wrote above the steps I made to add the jar in the java Build Path,do I have to set something else?

Comment: Can you try this: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1334802/how-can-i-use-external-jars-in-an-android-project

Answer (score 0):

Your problem is at runtime, not compile time. Create a `lib` folder, add your external jars. Now click on individual jars and add to build path.