# how to read a specific line in .java file and prints out ...?

Tags: java, android, string

i am creating a project in which i need to read a specific line starting from a keyword in .java file .

i will have to read .java files for :

```
Intent myIntent = new Intent(StudentMap.this, StudentPref.class);
StudentMap.this.startActivity(myIntent);
```

how will i read these two lines anywhere in the code . should i have to set regex for this but how ?

i am using :

```
public void onClick(View v) {

    TextView responseText = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.responseText);
    String myData = "";
String test = "Intent ";
   // String name="";
    switch (v.getId()) {
        case R.id.getExternalStorage:
            try {
                FileInputStream fis = new FileInputStream(myExternalFile);
                DataInputStream in = new DataInputStream(fis);
                BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(in));
                String strLine;

                while ((strLine = br.readLine()) != null){
                    myData = myData + strLine;



                    if (strLine.equals(test)) {

                        tv1.setText(tv1.getText() + strLine + "\n");
                    }
                    else{
                        tv1.setText(tv1.getText() + "nakaam" + "\n");

                    }

                }
                in.close();
            } catch (IOException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }

            responseText.setText("MySampleFile.java data retrieved from external Storage...");

            break;

    }

    tv1.setText(tv1.getText() + myData + "\n"+"\n"+"\n"+"end");

    //tv1.setText(tv1.getText() + strLine + "\n");


}
```

as far my knowledge Intent keyword is static in every file so i can get the start of line like "Intent" but how to read this line and the next line only from large file..?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want to start your String at the Keyword Intent, and read a Number of Lines after that, you can do something like this:

```
try {
    BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(new FileReader(file));
    int remainingLines = 0;
    String stringYouAreLookingFor = "";
    for(String line; (line = br.readLine()) != null; ) {
        if (line.startsWith("Intent")) {
            remainingLines = <Number of Lines you want to read after keyword>;
            stringYouAreLookingFor += line
        } else if (remainingLines > 0) {
            remainingLines--;
            stringYouAreLookingFor += line
        }    
    }
}
```

I guess this should give you an idea on how to search the String you are looking for.

Comment: is youwant a empty string or an integer?

Comment: its an integer. assuming you want the line containing Intent and the following 2 lines, you would put reamingLines = 2

Comment: line is a string . how can i assign string to an integer. it says incompatible type java.lang.string

Comment: if i put youwant as string it gives me two extra lines which contains text Intent which i dont want .

Comment: but the remaining two lines are also printed . which is required , this did brings me closer to goal . appreciated . but do tell how to remove the extra lines which also contain Intent name but does not required . i strictly need the line which is starting from Intent keyword . and the next line only or may be next 2, 3 lines,

Comment: i have changed my code, "youwant" was actually meant to be "stringYouAreLookingFor". Sorry for the mix up.

Comment: thats ok . but the problem remain what if i want the only line with starting word Intent and the next 2 , 3 line just . with this code i am getting all the lines containing the word Intent . if this solves that makes me accept this as an answer . thanks in advance :-)

Comment: Just use line.startsWith("Intent") instead of contains("Intent"). If there is only one line that starts with Intent you will just have to set the proper Number of Lines you want to have.

Comment: try(BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(new FileReader(myExternalFile)))  requires api 19 . how can i do this in min api 18 ?

Comment: Edited the code, this should work with api 18. What IDE are you using? it should help with auto complete if you are wondering why it wont run under api 19 ;)

Comment: Eclipse Adt juno . I am using for my android projects . I hav studio also . But unable to understand the studio . Eclipse works good.

Comment: studio is the way to go. its based on intellij and intellij is way more powerful than eclipse. besides, i think development of the eclipse plugin has been discontinued. EDIT: oh its not, anyway, studio is way better, and worth the time it takes to get used to it.