# Eclipse declared package does not match expected package

Tags: java, android, eclipse, parse-platform

Thanks for your help in advance! I am having a problem with declared packages, I have downloaded parse from github for android, My project is named Parr, when I go to add it to my project, I click on Parr then right click on src and try to add it, also tried the same under com.examle.parr, I am importing it by going into the file system and selecting the parse project I downloaded, I am selecting to add it into Parr/src/com/example/parr. every class added is added under, package com.parse; I can change them all manually to package com.examle.parr; but their is way to many and I know there is a right way to do it, any help will be much appreciated. On a side note is android studio recommended for use with parse, I do not see any instructions to add it to eclipse on there website, just android studio

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**On a side note is android studio recommended for use with parse, I do not see any instructions to add it to eclipse on there website, just android studio**

Android Studio is recommended for Android Development ,Google doesn't recommend to use Eclipse for Android Development , I would suggest you to switch from eclipse to Android Studio , Then will be much easier to solve the problems quickly you are facing now .

You can solve your problem in Eclipse too ,follow below steps :

1 . Download jar file from [here](https://github.com/ParsePlatform/Parse-SDK-Android#download)

2 . [Add](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1334802/how-can-i-use-external-jars-in-an-android-project) this jar file to you eclipse project (Android)

3 . Rebuild project .

4 . Run project .

Comment: Thanks I appreciate that, yea I added parse to a iphone app in less then 5 minutes, so far all day to add it to eclipse lol!

Comment: If this answer helped you , You can accept and recommend this answer for others who are still using Eclipse .

Comment: Give me a little bit, I would like to see how to do it, if for no other reason then because I just spent 8 hours trying to figure it out, and I rather not do the whole migrating from eclipse thing right now after doing this all day, but if i do not get anything soon I will give you credit for the answer, and i will diffidently take your advice as well!

Comment: All I have to do is change the package of all of the classes parse comes with, If u can add how in your answer i will accept it. I have done it before just don't remember how.

Comment: Can you give me the link of parse from where you have downloaded it ?

Comment: Download the jar file from here https://github.com/ParsePlatform/Parse-SDK-Android#download

Comment: No need to download complete project .

Comment: I am modifying above answer to meet your requirement .

Comment: I'm having no luck at all, so i have the jar downloaded, i am trying to add it by clicking import -> file system and i can not find it for anything, but when i go into my files is see it, idk what it is!!!

Comment: That one is outdated .

Comment: Try second one it will work for you definitely ,If you do properly .

Comment: i got it into my project, in my com.example i have mainAcativity and the jar file, is that where it should be, what do u mean by rebuild? clean it?

Comment: Yes , they should be there . There is a option in Project - Build Automatically ,I mean that .

Comment: If above discussion doesn't help you then you can ask same question to Parse support team , I have have tried a lot to help you. If you switch to Android Studio then its hardly 2 minutes of work .

Comment: It may take 2-3 days while getting response from parse . I have done good work on parse with Android Studio .

Comment: Officiallly there is no guide to integrate Parse in eclipse visit this link https://parse.com/apps/quickstart#parse_data/mobile/android/native/existing

Comment: Thank you for your help what i nightmare this is, i should have taken your advice from the start, i would prob be don't already, i got it into my project and got it working almost but still having some issues and it still not really working idk what it is! I am accepting your answer now, and up voted it, thank you very much, your the man!!!