# Error:Execution failed for task ':app:packageDebug'. > Duplicate files copied in APK META

Tags: java, android

I want to send mail.I have added javax.activation.jar and javax.mail when i debug my application it show this error

```
Error:Execution failed for task ':app:packageDebug'.
```

> Duplicate files copied in APK META-INF/LICENSE.txt
>       File 1: E:\getImageContent\app\libs\javax.mail-1.4.4.jar
>       File 2: E:\getImageContent\app\libs\javax.mail-1.4.4.jar
>
> please help me

Comment: i think you have copy file inside lib as well gradle so it create duplication error.

Comment: no sir,I have not copied that

Comment: please don't use sir Iam just beginner. i have  posted some steps try it

Comment: add lines in your bulid.gradle Try my answer.... @SiluniUpeksha

Answer (score 0):

follow below steps:

1> Copy all three jar and add into lib folder.

2> add in gradle following code inside dependencies:

```
    compile files('libs/activation.jar')
compile files('libs/additionnal.jar')
compile files('libs/mail.jar')
```

for more info see this link: [how to add external jar file in android studio](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1334802/how-can-i-use-external-jars-in-an-android-project/6859020#6859020)

Answer (score 0):

**Add this in your app build.gradle**

```
 packagingOptions {
    exclude 'META-INF/NOTICE.txt' // will not include NOTICE file
    exclude 'META-INF/LICENSE.txt' // will not include LICENSE file
}
```